# MySql - Better Schema for large table IP pairings?

Tags: mysql, optimization, schema, normalization

I'm trying to manage some internet logs. I'm essentially capturing what IPs are reaching out to what other IPs and making reports on it.

Problem is there's a ton of chatter and I'm not sure if I can make my schema any better.

my table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `IpChatter` (
  `Id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SourceIp` bigint(20) NULL,
  `DestinationIp` bigint(20) NULL,
  `SourcePort` int(11) NULL,
  `DestinationPort` int(11) NULL,
  `FKToSomeTableWithExtraMetaDataId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `PK_IpChatter` PRIMARY KEY (`Id` ASC)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;


CREATE INDEX `IX_IpChatter_FKToSomeTableWithExtraMetaDataId` ON `IpChatter`  (`FKToSomeTableWithExtraMetaDataId`) using HASH;
CREATE INDEX `IX_IpChatter_Main_Query_SourceIp` ON `IpChatter`        (`SourceIp`);
CREATE INDEX `IX_IpChatter_Main_Query_DestinationIp` ON `IpChatter`   (`DestinationIp`);
CREATE INDEX `IX_IpChatter_Main_Query_SourcePort` ON `IpChatter`      (`SourcePort`);
CREATE INDEX `IX_IpChatter_Main_Query_DestinationPort` ON `IpChatter` (`DestinationPort`);


ALTER TABLE `IpChatter` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_IpChatter_FKToSomeTableWithExtraMetaData` 
FOREIGN KEY (`FKToSomeTableWithExtraMetaDataId`) REFERENCES `FKToSomeTableWithExtraMetaData` (`Id`)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Right now I've got 2mill rows of data and pulls back data I need in about 4sec. However this is from using relatively light testing data. I'd imagine the size of the data being 30X larger in the final product. So that 4 sec will surely mean 2mins in the final product. Is there a better way I could normalize this data or have I hit a bottle neck and there isn't much I can do? Also, Are the indexes I picked ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I figured it out. I guess I just needed to type out the problem to help me think up a solution.

So after looking at my data I've noticed a lot of pairings are repeated but under a different FKToSomeTableWithExtraMetaDataId value.

So tells me I can normalize the data by creating a table with distinct pairings of SourceIp`,`DestinationIp`,`SourcePort`,`DestinationPort`. Then create a lookup table to join up that table with the ToSomeTableWithExtraMetaData table.

This reduces my raw IP data by 1700%! This will give a tremendous increase in performance when searching for a range of IPs and now it has to go though far less rows. Plus with the lookup table I have greater flexibility on how I can query.

```
CREATE TABLE `IpChatter` (
  `Id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SourceIp` bigint(20) NULL,
  `DestinationIp` bigint(20) NULL,
  `SourcePort` int(11) NULL,
  `DestinationPort` int(11) NULL,
  `FKToSomeLookupTableId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `PK_IpChatter` PRIMARY KEY (`Id` ASC)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;


CREATE INDEX `IX_IpChatter_FKToSomeLookupTableId` ON `IpChatter`  (`FKToSomeLookupTableId`) using HASH;
CREATE INDEX `IX_IpChatter_Main_Query_SourceIp` ON `IpChatter`        (`SourceIp`);
CREATE INDEX `IX_IpChatter_Main_Query_DestinationIp` ON `IpChatter`   (`DestinationIp`);
CREATE INDEX `IX_IpChatter_Main_Query_SourcePort` ON `IpChatter`      (`SourcePort`);
CREATE INDEX `IX_IpChatter_Main_Query_DestinationPort` ON `IpChatter` (`DestinationPort`);


ALTER TABLE `IpChatter` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_IpChatter_FKToSomeLookupTable` 
FOREIGN KEY (`FKToSomeLookupTableId`) REFERENCES `FKToSomeLookupTable` (`Id`)
ON DELETE CASCADE;


CREATE TABLE `FKToSomeLookupTable` (
  `FKToSomeTableWithExtraMetaDataId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `IpChatterId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `PK_FKToSomeLookupTable` PRIMARY KEY (`Id` ASC)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX `IX_IpChatter_FKToSomeTableWithExtraMetaDataId` ON `FKToSomeLookupTable`  (`FKToSomeTableWithExtraMetaDataId`) using HASH;
CREATE INDEX `IX_IpChatter_IpChatterId` ON `FKToSomeLookupTable`  (`IpChatterId`) using HASH;

ALTER TABLE `FKToSomeLookupTable` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_FKToSomeLookupTable_FKToSomeTableWithExtraMetaData` 
FOREIGN KEY (`FKToSomeTableWithExtraMetaDataId`) REFERENCES `FKToSomeTableWithExtraMetaData` (`Id`)
ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `FKToSomeLookupTable` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_FKToSomeLookupTable_IpChatter` 
FOREIGN KEY (`IpChatterId`) REFERENCES `IpChatter` (`Id`)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: Yeah, it's called [Rubber Duck Debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Answer (score 0):

Shrink the table size.  Smaller is one way to help (some) with the speed.

IPv4 can be packed into `INT UNSIGNED`, which is 4 bytes versus your current 8-byte BIGINT.  IPv6, on the other hand, needs `BINARY(16)`; what you have will not work.

Port number, I think, will fit in a 2-byte `SMALLINT UNSIGNED`.

Are you expecting your tables to be bigger than 4 billion rows?  If not, use `INT UNSIGNED` instead of `BIGINT` for ids.

Get rid of `FOREIGN KEYs`, they slow down things; meanwhile, the constraints have never triggered an error, have they?  Do you really use the overhead of `CASCADE`?

Don't index every column.  Look at your queries and index the columns *or combinations of columns* that would benefit `SELECTs`, `UPDATEs`, and `DELETEs`.

Please show the queries; without them, we cannot judge the performance.